# A local variable or function named 'tablesInDatabases' is already defined in this scope

Tags: c#

I want to be able to use an already defined variable to create a new

List already defined variable = new List();

I was wondering if there was a workaround

```
Console.Write("Choose name for new table: ");
string tables = Console.ReadLine();

string tablesInDatabases = new string($"{dataBases[chooseDatabase] + tables}");

List<string> tablesInDatabases = new List<string>();
```

CS0128 A local variable or function named 'tablesInDatabases' is already defined in this scope
                                                                         Question edit:
rewrote it to:

```
Console.Write("Choose name for new table: ");
string table = Console.ReadLine();
string inThisDatabase = new string(dataBases[chooseDatabase]);
tables.Add(table);                             
tableBelongTo.Add(inThisDatabase);
```

Comment: You can't declare twice a variable with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/392713). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to be able to create a new list for every new table I make for the specific database - I'm still quite a beginner as it shows glaringly painful

Comment: rewrote it to:                                                                     Console.Write("Choose name for new table: ");                                           string table = Console.ReadLine();
                                                                                                                     
string inThisDatabase = new string(dataBases[chooseDatabase]);

tables.Add(table);
tableBelongTo.Add(inThisDatabase);

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. Give them different names - possibly to describe the different jobs that they are doing, since a List is doing a different job to a string.

For example:

```
string numberOfTablesText = "...";
List<string> tableNames = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it like a normal variable, then the answer is no. How is your compiler supposed to know which  one is meant to be used? By the way you use it?

Doing that would only be possible for local variables as long as their lifetime does not interfeir or inside of different namespaces / classes, but even if you could somehow make this work you really shouldn't. It does not only make the code unreadable and really hard to follow, i guarantee you that you will get a crazy amount of build errors if this project  would grow! At least call your variables something like `sTablesInDatabases` and `lTablesInDatabases` (s for string, l for List)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self explanatory. tablesInDatabases variable is already defined.

```
Console.Write("Choose name for new table: ");
string tables = Console.ReadLine();

string tablesInDatabases = new string($"{dataBases[chooseDatabase] + tables}");

List<string> tablesAsList = new List<string>();
```

A good reference to check is [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0128) for the error.